# Aggregate method for each document resulting from find method in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to execute this aggregate query:

```
db.collection('mycoll').aggregate([
        {
          $search: {
            index: 'default',
            text: {
              query: 'night',
              path: {
                wildcard: '*',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ])


    })
```

for each document resulting from my find method:

here is my find method:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('subs').find(
      { name: { $regex: 'dexter', $options: '$i' } },
      { projection: { _id: 0, content: 0 } }
    )
    .toArray((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new err();
      }
      res.json({
        length: result.length,
        body: { result },
      });
    });
});
```

I know I probably have to use forEach and create a function, but I couldn't find out what to put in this function, I assume ## Heading ##it should be something like that:

```
 .find(
      { name: { $regex: 'dexter', $options: '$i' } },
      { projection: { _id: 0, content: 0 } }
    ).forEach(()=>{})
    .toArray((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new err();
      }
      res.json({
        length: result.length,
        body: { result },
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in several different ways, here is the simplest code sample I could produce:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const result = await db.collection('subs').find(
        {name: {$regex: 'dexter', $options: '$i'}},
        {projection: {_id: 0, content: 0}}
    ).toArray();

    const finalResults = await Promise.all(result.map(async (each) => {
        each.textSearchResults = await db.collection('mycoll').aggregate([
            {
                $search: {
                    index: 'default',
                    text: { // decide what your query is based on each document
                        query: each.name,
                        path: {
                            wildcard: '*',
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        ])
        return each
    }))


    res.json({
        length: result.length,
        body: {result},
    });
});
```